# What is the use of <managed-bean-scope> tag in face-config.xml file?

Tags: java, jsf

```
   <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>tagTypeEnumAddNewFO</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>packagename.classname</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```

Here what is the use of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells how long the object is supposed to live in the application before it is instantiated again. In this example, it will only be "alive" for the remainder of the view you are on. So typically one request on the same view.

Other examples are `session`, which will remain in memory until your session expires, or explicitly is removed.

Answer (score 1):

The scope in `JSF` means `lifetime` of the bean.

There are several scopes like `Session, View` etc.

To understand more about it visit Blog by `JSF` Expert BalusC [here](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)